# "Class" continues working without being referenced globally

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I made an image slider "class" and originally instantiated it as:

`var foo = new Slider(document.getElementById("featuredSlider"), 900);`

I tried removing `var foo =` and it continues to work which was surprising to me. What makes it continue working? Is it a bad idea to not reference it globally?

On a side note, `"featuredSlider"` is the `id` of a `<div>` tag. It contains some number of `<a`> tags and each contain `<img>` tags.

```
function Slider(inElement, inStep) {
    if (!inElement) return;

    this.element = inElement;
    this.start = 0;
    this.end = 0;

    var self = this;
    var limit = inElement.getElementsByTagName("a").length*inStep;
    setInterval(function() {
        self.start = self.end;
        self.end = (self.end+inStep)%limit;
        self.animate(this.start < this.end ? 1 : -1);
    }, 3000);
}

Slider.prototype.animate = function(inZeno) {
    this.start += ((this.end-this.start)>>2)+inZeno;
    this.element.style.left = this.start+"px";

    if (this.start !== this.end) {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            self.animate(self.start < self.end ? 1 : -1);
        }, 33);
    }
}

//new Slider(document.getElementById("featuredSlider"), 900);
var foo = new Slider(document.getElementById("featuredSlider"), 900);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried removing var foo = and it continues to work which was surprising to me. What makes it continue working?

Because references to it are kept by the timer system, because it's set up callbacks to functions (closures) that reference it via `setInterval` and `setTimeout`. So references to the necessary parts of it are kept around as long as those timers are still held.

The function it's giving to `setInterval` here:

```
setInterval(function() {
    self.start = self.end;
    self.end = (self.end+inStep)%limit;
    self.animate(this.start < this.end ? 1 : -1);
}, 3000);
```

is a *closure* over the call to `Slider`. So all of the things in scope within the closure are kept around as long as the closure (function) is around. Since that timer is never cancelled, the timer system keeps those references alive. (If "closure" is unfamiliar or only slightly familiar, don't worry: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html).)

> Is it a bad idea to not reference it globally?

No, that's fine. If it keeps working and you don't need the reference, there's no need to store a reference to it. This was quite a common pattern back when a lot of people used script.aculo.us, which used `new` for about half of its effects.

Comment: Can you explain "attached itself to the `div`"? I've never heard of such a thing

Comment: @asimes: Set up event handlers on the div, set data properties on the div, etc. For instance: `var self = this; div.addEventListener("click", function() { self.doSomething(); }, false);` Now the `div` has a reference to `self`, which is `this`, and the object is kept around as long as the `div` has that reference to it.

Comment: @PatrickEvans: Yes, thanks. I have to admit, I assumed the code block was the OP *using* the slider, not the code of the slider. Fixed.

Comment: @asimes: Sorry, it doesn't attach itself to the `div`, as Patrick says it's the timer system that keeps it alive. (In fact, it's the other way around: Even if you remove the `div` from the DOM, unless you cancel the timer, the slider will keep the `div` in memory, disconnected from the DOM.)

Comment: I had the same impression till I looked a bit closer :)

Comment: Great, thank you. I am roughly familiar with closure, as far as I know anonymous functions keep variables outside their scope that they reference, I'll read your link in a minute.